# How to add arraylist to listview when clicking on recycler item in Android?

Tags: android, exception

How to add an arraylist to listview when clicking on recycler item in Android? When I'm trying to add it's showing an `index out of bounds` exception.

Here is my code, I am trying to pass packagelist values to servicenames.

```
List<AvailableServices> serviceNames = null;
final PlanGsonResponse.ListOfPackages packagesList = mPackageData.get(position);

holder.mPackageInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.mListOfServicesDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        serviceNames=packagesList.getAvailableServicesUnderPackage();
        for (int i = 0; i <= serviceNames.size(); i++) {
            ss.add(i, serviceNames.get(i).getServiceName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            mContext,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            ss
        );

        holder.mServices.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your for loop as shown below:

```
for (int i=0;i<serviceNames.size();i++)
{
    ss.add(i,serviceNames.get(i).getServiceName());
}
```

Replace "<=" with "<"

Comment: Thanku so much @Mehul Kanzariya, You saved   my time.